# cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2() error

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, background-subtraction

Could anyone help me on this one?
I'm trying for a background Subtracting method and used to perfectly run fine while using the cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG() method in previous opencv versions.

```
import cv2
backsub = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2()
capture = cv2.VideoCapture("headcount.avi")
i = 0
if capture:
  while True:

    ret, frame = capture.read()
    if ret:
        fgmask = backsub.apply(frame, None, 0.01)
        erode=cv2.erode(fgmask,Nonei,terations=3)
        moments=cv2.moments(erode,True)
```

But using opencv 3.1.0 i'm facing problems while using the cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2() function and this is the error i'm getting,while applying mask operation

Error:
 fgmask = backsub.apply(frame, 1, 0.01)
error: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp:163: error: (-215) The data should normally be NULL! in function NumpyAllocator::allocate

Comment: Try with 1) `fgmask = backsub.apply(frame)`, or `fgmask = backsub.apply(frame, learningRate=0.01)` or `backsub.apply(frame, fgmask, 0.01)`

Comment: Not getting anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is OpenCV 3.1 bug.
You could disable OpenCL support as workaround.
Details is here
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/6055

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your code.

```
cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)
```

More information here:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6055